# Telling when a MySQL update has finished executing in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm curious about this.

How do you tell if a MySQL update has finished executing in Java? I've tried searching on Google, but to no avail.

Is executeUpdate() synchronous or asynchronous?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you refer to a JDBC statement object. This method is synchronous. So when it returns, it has executed the statement on the DB.

You may also be able to see how many rows it updated: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Cool, this answered the question accurately. Thanks!